# header cell on top of list

Tags: uitableview

I have a tableview with a list. I want to add a cell to the top of the list that shows what is being displayed below. So each item in the list is a Name with Age and Gender next to it. I want a header cell on top that actually says "Name  Age  Gender" so that people actually know what data is being displayed. I also want this cell to not scroll when the rest of the list scrolls downwards.

Do I add another cell to show these things or should I do it via another method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about a header of a table view section. If so, you can implement the header cell methods in `UITableViewDataSource`:

```
-tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:
```

Alternatively, if you want to get fancy and use your own view for a section header try implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
```

Comment: I need to put in 3 separate strings for the header in one section. I have one section in the tableview and an example cell would look like this: Name    Age   Gender. so i want the header to say those three words on top. Is the best way to just use spaces in @"" to properly align it with the data below.

Comment: So you're looking for something like a table with 3 columns? You could use spaces, but a better way would be to add a custom view with the second method I recommended. You could better control the 3 `UILabel`s you would need in the header.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i want. So how/where do i add a custom view? Im currently using storyboard and am a bit confused where as to place the view for all this to work. Do I add a custom view to the cell (im currently using prototype cell of custom class and there is one showing in storyboard) or to the tableview?

Comment: To add a custom view, implement the second method I listed above in the view controller (likely a table view controller) that is acting as the table view's delegate. Then build your view inside that method. The return type on that method is `UIView*`, so return the custom built view from that method.

Comment: Also, Google is a tremendous resource: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=custom+UITableView+header+cell&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=custom+UITableView+header+view&rls=en. The documentation is great too: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html